# S3 static hosting deactivate URL encoding

Tags: amazon-s3, jwt, urlencode

I'm using the s3 static hosting for an react app.

Its handed a jwt token which contains a URL, decoded it looks like this:

```
app/{version}/index.html
```

the {version} part is replaced with a version number:

```
url.replace('{version}', "v".concat(apiVersion))
```

locally this works fine but in s3 the URL looks like this:

```
app/%7Bversion%7D/index.html
```

Is there any why to prevent the URL encoding in s3 on the jwt decode?

also did add

```
url.replace('%7Bversion%7D', "v".concat(apiVersion))
```

which works then in s3 but not locally.

Also tried to configure redirect rules, but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

```
decodeURI(url).replace('{version}', "v".concat(apiVersion))
```